# BufferedImage to array

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, bufferedimage

What are the advantages of converting a buffered image into an array of integers?I assume that i can manipulate the array and cross process the picture .Is that so?

Comment: Tag the language you're talking about (Java?).

Comment: How does *"cross process the picture"* differ from *"process the picture"*?  What does 'cross' mean here?

Comment: Yes i meant processing the picture as in adjusting RGB colours:)

Comment: @PherricOxide sorry my bad.I added the tag later as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are referring to [getRgb()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) method of BufferedImage class.

Supposing you want to modify the whole image or a big portion of it, retrieving the pixel array, and perform operations on it could be considerely faster than accessing each single pixel through method calls such as [setRgb()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

SwingX introduces the AbstractFilter class for BufferedImage. Here is an example:

- http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/swinglabs/swingx/0.9/swingx-0.9-sources.jar!/org/jdesktop/swingx/image/GaussianBlurFilter.java?format=ok

For simple editing use one of this examples:

- http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt.image/imagepixel.html
- [Buffered image pixel manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742444/buffered-image-pixel-manipulation)
- [How do I create a BufferedImage from array containing pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396159/how-do-i-create-a-bufferedimage-from-array-containing-pixels)

Answer (score 0):

Having a `BufferedImage` into memory as an array of `int` values could help you apply filters on the image by processing the `int` values into memory and then setting the result back to another `BufferedImage`.